# Lazy column goes off screen from bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am using ComposeView in xml layout

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/inputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />
```

Code Lazy Column

```
LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(align = Bottom)
        state = lazyColumnListState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
```

At the same time, my list goes below the `inputLayout` and I do not see the last elements of the list, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you try to give LazyColumn modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()?

Comment: @tasjapr it's not suitable for me. the list is searchable and therefore it should change in size, depending on the number of elements